# Drag file from winforms to outlook 2016 not working

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, outlook

My winforms application allows users to drag files from the application to explorer and to outlook.
This has always worked very well, except for the new outlook 2013 and higher versions.

If I drag to explorer the file is copied as expected.
When dragging to outlook version prior to 2013 everything works, but when dragging into outlook 2013 or higher nothing happens.

I found that when I drag explicitly to the 'attachments box' in the new outlook, then it does works.
But the attachment-textbox isn't shown by default so this is not very helpfull.
Also, when I drag from explorer to outlook it does works, even if not dragged explicitly to the 'attachments box' so it is possible.

This is the code I use to start the drag operation:

```
string[] files = new string[1];
files[0] = @"c:\test\test.pdf";
DataObject dataObject = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, files);
DoDragDrop(dataObject, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

I found another post here with the same problem :
[How to drag files from c# winforms app to outlook message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232446/how-to-drag-files-from-c-sharp-winforms-app-to-outlook-message#)

The solution here was to revert the project from framework 4.5 to 4.0 which is not an option I would like to use.

So my question is, how can I start a drag operation from winforms that will work in outlook 2013 or higher wihout having to drag explicitly to the 'attachment box', just like when dragging from explorer ?

The files beeing dragged are 99% pdf files, sometimes a jpg.

EDIT: If someone knows how to configure outlook2013 and higher versions to always show the 'attachment box' this would be a workable workaround for me.